# Using subqueries with doctrine / Errors with aliases

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine

I'm trying to make a simple query with a subquery in a orWhere clause (with Doctrine).

As always, Doctrine tries to rename every aliases and completely destroys the queries...

Here's an example:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Actualite a')
    ->where('a.categorie_id =?', $id)
    ->orWhere('a.categorie_id IN (select id from cat.categorie as cat where cat.categorie_id =?)', $id)
    ->execute();
```

Which in MySQL would make something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM actualite a 
WHERE a.categorie_id = 1 OR a.categorie_id IN (SELECT cat.id FROM categorie cat WHERE cat.categorie_id = 1);
```

Everything is right about it, but then again Doctrine destroys it:
Couldn't find class cat

Every time I try to do something a little complex with Doctrine, I have errors with aliases. Any advice or ideas about how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What if to retain full table name ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL example you've provided is fine but the corresponding Doctrine syntax has a couple of errors. Here's a clean version:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('a.*')
    ->from('Actualite a')
    ->where('a.categorie_id = ?', $id)
    ->orWhere('a.categorie_id IN (SELECT cat.id FROM Categorie cat WHERE cat.categorie_id = ?)', $id)
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `createSubquery()` to explicitely tell doctrine about your nested subquery. So your query should look something like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('a.*')
    ->from('Actualite a')
    ->where('a.categorie_id = ?', $id)
;

$subquery = $q->createSubquery()
    ->select("cat.id")
    ->from("Categorie cat")
    ->where("cat.categorie_id = ?", $id)
;

$q->orWhere('a.categorie_id IN ('.$subquery->getDql().')')->execute();
```

Another example can be found here:

http://www.philipphoffmann.de/2012/08/taming-doctrine-subqueries/

Answer (score 0):

I think you query should be like this add the select and remove as

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('a.id')
    ->from('Actualite a')
    ->where('a.categorie_id =?', $id)
    ->orWhere('a.categorie_id IN (select id from cat.categorie cat where cat.categorie_id =?)', $id)
    ->execute();
```

Try this may help you.

Thanks

Comment: FUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU!!! Couldn't find class cat... It doesn't work :\ But thanks for trying anyways, very appreciated.